# How to get tag number of UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xib, nib

I am using Various button, and i have set tag of it from Xib files. And Connected  all button to single method `-(void) note:(id)sender`.

Now i want to retrive tag number.so that i can see which button is clicked

```
-(void) note:(id)sender

{

    NotesClass *note = [[NotesClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"NotesClass" bundle:nil];
    note.notetag = sender;
    NSLog(@"%@",note.notetag);
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:note animated:YES];

}
```

When Print that NSlog I get this output:

```
<UIButton: 0x4e70350; frame = (227 119; 20 18); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x4e70480>>
```

Any one can please help me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try following code, it will surely help you out

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSInteger bTag = button.tag;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the tag with

```
sender.tag
```

Comment: i have tried that but its showing error. following error "Request for member 'tag' in something not a structure or union"

Comment: Are you printing it in NSLog? *tag* is an integer property. You have to "%d" as the format to print integers.

Answer (score 1):

```
(void) note:(id)sender

{

    NotesClass *note = [[NotesClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"NotesClass" bundle:nil];
    note.notetag = [sender tag];
    NSLog(@"%d",note.notetag);
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:note animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void) note:(id)sender

{

NotesClass *note = [[NotesClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"NotesClass" bundle:nil];
note.notetag = [sender tag];
NSLog(@"%d",note.notetag);
//Another option is to use

UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
NSLog(@"%d",button.tag);
[self.navigationController pushViewController:note animated:YES];

}
```

Its `%d` not `%@` as `tag` is of `int` type

Answer (score 1):

```
in .H file write below code

@interface tagViewController : UIViewController {

    UIButton *btn1;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIButton *btn1;
-(IBAction)btnclicked:(id)sender;
@end

and in .M file write below code

-(IBAction)btnclicked:(id)sender
{
    btn1 = (UIButton *)sender;

    NSLog(@"You Press Button No %d",btn1.tag);

}

Don't forgate maping of your button Suppose i have three button and i set it tag 1,2,3 and then after mapping all of them with  btnclicked: in TouchUp Inside Event and then after run it it's working...
```